# Set redis key/value with camel-redis

Tags: redis, apache-camel

I want to set a key/value pair using camel-redis. I try:

```
spring-redis://localhost:6379?command=SET&CamelRedis.key=testkey&CamelRedis.value=100
```

but no joy. I get the error:

```
There are 2 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{key=testkey, value=100}]
```

Although there are plenty of examples about how to subscribe etc. I do not find a single example on how to set a key/value pair. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CamelRedis.Key` and  `CamelRedis.Value` (beware they are case sensitive) are message headers not URI parameters

```
<route>
    <from  uri="direct:intput"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelRedis.Key"><constant>testkey</constant></setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelRedis.Value"><constant>100</constant></setHeader>
    <to uri="spring-redis://localhost:6379?command=SET"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Can I somehow achieve this w simple URI parameters? Isn't it supposed that I can express this also in Camel DSL style?